# Strip part of HTML content in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have part of HTML page as:

```
<div class="myClass"></div>​
```

Now I have some html code in a javascript variable as:

```
var alpha = "<div><p>Hello</p><img src='abc.jpg'/></div>"​
```

I want only the  part i.e.  of the variable to be placed inside div of class 'myClass'. Is it possible?

Comment: what part? `p` or `img`?

Comment: @caligula - I require only img part

Comment: @Ankit Gautam - I mean that I want to strip out only <img src='abc.jpg'/> and paste it into <div> having class 'myClass'

Answer (score 2):

```
var alpha = "<div><p>Hello</p><img src='abc.jpg'/></div>";
var img = $(alpha).find('img');
var html = $('<p>').append(img).html();

$('.myClass').append($(html))​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H64VV/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myClass").html($(alpha).find("img"))
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H64VV/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var alpha = "<div><p>Hello</p><img src='abc.jpg'/></div>"
$('.myClass').append($(alpha).find('img'));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

`$(".myClass").html(alpha);`